# Calculate the given indefinite integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Calculate the following integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$$

I believe I need to choose a good substitution, but the problem is that I haven't found it yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Set $x=\tan y\implies dx=?$

$$\int \frac1{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx=\int\dfrac{\sec y\ dy}{1-\tan^2y}=\int\dfrac{\cos y\ dy}{1-2\sin^2y}$$

Set $\sin y=u$

Or directly, $u=\dfrac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Comment: Can you, please, explain how you got what's on the last line?

Comment: @GeorgeR., $$\sin y=\dfrac{\tan y}{\sec y}=\dfrac{\tan y}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2y}}$$ for $-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

To evaluate integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(lx^2+m)\sqrt{ax^2+b}}\,dx,$ substitute $\sqrt{ax^2+b}=xz$ for another function $z$. This would lead to the primitive yielding an $\arctan$ function.